# How do I mount the linux virtual machine cloned disk?

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, kvm

I created a CentOS cloned disk image as specified in the URL [here](http://www.linux-kvm.com/content/how-you-can-use-qemukvm-base-images-be-more-productive-part-1) and I was able to mount the base disk image as specified below

```
To get base disk image details:
   1) fdisk -lu raw.img

To mount the base disk image:
   2) losetup /dev/loop0 raw.img -o $((9766912   * 512))
   3) file -s /dev/loop0
   4) mount /dev/loop0 /mnt
   5) cd /mnt
   6) ls -l
       bin/    etc/    lost+found/     mnt/    orig_boot/  
       sbin/   sys/           var/    boot/   home/   media/          
       proc/   selinux/        tmp/  wlcv_root_info/ ....

 To umount the base disk image:
   7) umount /mnt
   8) losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

BUT I could not get the same on the cloned disk :( and I getting below error message

```
-sh-4.1# mount /dev/loop0 /mnt
     mount: you must specify the filesystem type

 -sh-4.1# mount -t ext3 /dev/loop0 /mnt
   mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
          missing codepage or helper program, or other error
          In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
          dmesg | tail  or so
```

I tried with ext2, ext3 and ext4 filesystem type but nothing seems to be helpful. Please guide me on mounting the clone disk so that I can view all the files that were created in the cloned disk.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

```
mount -r <fstype> <fsdev> <fsdir>

       -r:     Mount read only.
       fstype: The filesystem type to mount
       fsdev:  The name of a block device to mount.
       fsdir:  The directory to mount to.
```

**EDIT:**

Donno what is happening at your side. You probably give a try. Have a look at this problem [Mount complains a wrong fs type, bad option, or a bad superblock](http://slopjong.de/2013/09/11/mount-complains-a-wrong-fs-type-bad-option-or-a-bad-superblock/). Also try `mount -t auto`

Comment: Yes I do but of no use. :(

Comment: Please check the EDIT and let me know it helps or not.